# realloc overwrite variable (Xilinx SDK on a Zynq SoC (Cortex A9))

Tags: c, arm, realloc, xilinx

As mentioned I have a Zynq SoC (ZC706 Eval Board) and I'm trying to read an image from the SD Card. To do this I'm using the FatFs lib (http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html).
In my code I read 4096 Byte from the file and save it to a buffer. After that i copy the buffer to an unsigned char pointer that size I increase after every read operation.

Then I'm using realloc, the for loop in the copyU32ArrayToUnsignedCharArray function 'failed' because the size variable is overwritten by the out array.

Code that overwrite the "size" in the copyU32ArrayToUnsignedCharArray function:

```
u32 buffer[1024];
unsigned char *img = NULL;
bytesreaded = 0;
for (;;) {
    br=0;
    fr = f_read(&fil, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &br); /* Read a chunk of source file */
    if (fr || br == 0)
        break; /* error or eof */

    img = realloc(img,br);
    copyU32ArrayToUnsignedCharArray(buffer, &img[bytesreaded], br/4); // /4 because u32(32 bit) in to unsigned char(8 bit)
    bytesreaded += br; // update readed bytes 
}
```

The code that worked:

```
    u32 buffer[1024];
unsigned char *img = NULL;
img = malloc(512*512*3+100);
bytesreaded = 0;
for (;;) {
    br=0;
    fr = f_read(&fil, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &br); /* Read a chunk of source file */
    if (fr || br == 0)
        break; /* error or eof */

    copyU32ArrayToUnsignedCharArray(buffer, &img[bytesreaded], br/4); // /4 because u32(32 bit) in to unsigned char(8 bit)
    bytesreaded += br; // update readed bytes 
}
```

The copyU32ArrayToUnsignedCharArray function:

```
void copyU32ArrayToUnsignedCharArray(u32 *in, unsigned char* out, uint size){
int i,x;

x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(size != 1024)
        break;
    in[i] = Xil_In32BE(&in[i]);
    out[x] = (u32) in[i] >> 24;
    out[x + 1] = (u32) in[i] >> 16 & 0x00FF;
    out[x + 2] = (u32) in[i] >> 8 & 0x0000FF;
    out[x + 3] = (u32) in[i] & 0x000000FF;
    x += 4;
}
}
```

I want to use realloc because I don't know how big the image will be that I read.

**Update:**
Some further information to the code that doesn't work. I debugged it and the pointer to *img isn't null, so the realloc was successfully. If I'm using gdb the following things happen in the copyU32ArrayToUnsignedCharArray function:
 - pointer to the variable "out" is 0x001125a8
 - the address of the "size" variable is 0x0011309c (the value that is stored at this location is correct)
 - the space in memory between this two variables is 0xaf4 = 2804 dec (difference of the two addresses)
 - if the for loop within the copyU32ArrayToUnsignedCharArray function reached i=702 and x=2808 the size variable is changed to another value

Sincerely,
Arno

Comment: _"...'failed' because the size variable is overwritten by the out array."_ - how do you figure that? `size` is function argument whose address is never taken, so doesn't even necessarily have storage that could be overwritten (indeed, [that function can easily do its thing entirely in registers](https://godbolt.org/g/GVXUwS)). Also, given that you're not checking the return value, how do you know `realloc()` itself doesn't fail (or given that this would appear to be a bare-metal environment, isn't simply implemented as `return NULL;`)?

Comment: I forget to mention that the application is bare-metal. I debugged the program with gdb and take a look at the memory. The address from the pointer was 0x1125a8, the address from size was 0x11309c. So there is a space between this from 0xaf4. The size variable is overwritten then variable i is 701 and x 2804. If I convert the decimal number 2804 to hex i get the difference that i calculated before (2804 = 0xaf4)

Comment: Your comment is totally unclear.... Could you elaborate a bit more? Are you saying that the `size` parameter address into is, at a certain point of c`opyU32ArrayToUnsignedCharArray` execution, overwritten?....

Comment: BTW what @Notlikethat wrote you is the point: you **have to** check `realloc` return value to be sure that `realloc` successfully allocated required memory.

Comment: Well, that rather suggests that for some reason your stack and heap are far too close together and running into each other, in which case the problem isn't anything to do with any of this code (I guess repeated `realloc()` calls might churn the heap enough to exacerbate it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the hint from Notlikethat. The problem was the small heap size. Increasing the heap is done by editing the linker script file